# Centering a div next to another div (but not inside the other div)

Tags: javascript, html, css

Please see the below snippet.

I want to have an element, 'modal', be vertically centered over another div, 'element', regardless of where that other div is, its margin, etc. However, I do not want to place the 'modal' div inside of the 'element' div (because of some restrictions to how I can use the react component I am trying to create). How can I have one div be positioned relative to another div without placing the first div inside the second? Do I need to use some javascript or something to detect the position of this 'element' div? Are there any pure css solutions? Thanks.

```css
.container {
  border: 2px solid red;
  margin: 5rem;
  height: 20rem;
  width: 20rem;
  position: relative;
}

.element {
  background: pink;
  height: 10rem;
  width: 10rem;
  margin: 3rem;
}

.modal {
  position: absolute;
  background: green;
  height: 2rem;
  width: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="modal" />
  <div class="element" />
</div>
```

Comment: The easiest way is to wrap these 2 inside a 3rd div. Let's call them `.wrapper`, `.element` and `.modal`. Make `.wrapper { position: relative; }`. Leave `.element` as it is but without any margin _(transpose that margin on `.wrapper`)_, it will expand `.wrapper` depending on its size. And leave `.modal { position: absolute; }`. That way, `.modal` will be absolutely positioned, but relative to the `.wrapper`, which happens to have the same size as `.element` because it wraps it. Exactly like what you have with `.container`, but with no margins/paddings between the `.wrapper` and the `.element`

Comment: Thanks @blex but I need to position this div relative to the 'element' div regardless of where it is or what margin it has.

Comment: Ok, adding the _"regardless of where it is or what margin it has"_ requirement drastically reduces the possibilities. I can only think of a JS solution in that case. Maybe I'll try in a couple of minutes

Comment: I just started giving it a try, and I already have a question. Here, both your modal and element are inside a `.container` with a `position: relative;`. Are both elements **always** going to have the same `relative` ancestor? (`relative` in the sense that an absolute position given to the modal will be relative to that element)

Comment: Yes, they can always be wrapped in a relative parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the *"regardless of where it is or what margin it has"* requirement drastically reduces the possibilities. I can only think of a JS solution in that case.

If they both have the same offset parent (closest `position: relative`), you can create a function which calculates the center of the `.element`, and offsets the modal according to its size:

```js
// Centers an element relative to another one
function centerElement(el, rel) {
  var offset = getOffset(el);
  var center = getCenterPoint(rel);
  el.style.top  = center.top  - offset.height / 2 + 'px';
  el.style.left = center.left - offset.width  / 2 + 'px';
}

// Returns the center point of an element
function getCenterPoint(el) {
  var elOffset = getOffset(el);
  return {
    top:  elOffset.top  + elOffset.height / 2,
    left: elOffset.left + elOffset.width  / 2
  };
}

// Returns the offset of an element
function getOffset(el) {
  return {
    top: el.offsetTop,
    left: el.offsetLeft,
    width: el.offsetWidth,
    height: el.offsetHeight
  };
}

// Usage
var element = document.querySelector('.element'),
    modal   = document.querySelector('.modal');

centerElement(modal, element);
```

```css
.container {
  border: 2px solid red;
  margin: 5rem;
  height: 20rem;
  width: 20rem;
  position: relative;
}

.element {
  background: pink;
  height: 10rem;
  width: 10rem;
  margin: 3rem;
}

.modal {
  position: absolute;
  background: green;
  height: 2rem;
  width: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="modal"></div>
  <div class="element"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

CSS-Grid can do that:

```css
.container {
  border: 2px solid red;
  margin: 1rem auto;
  height: 20rem;
  width: 20rem;
  position: relative;
  display:grid;
  place-items:center;
  
}

.modal, .element {
grid-row:1;
grid-column:1;
}

.element {
  background: pink;
  height: 10rem;
  width: 10rem;
  margin: 3rem;
}

.modal {
  background: green;
  height: 2rem;
  width: 2rem;
  z-index:1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="modal"></div>
  <div class="element"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks @Paulie_D but I need to do this regardless of where the 'element' div is. Your solution centers it in a larger container.